Internet not working after updating drivers
I updated my Nvidia Driver on my Ubuntu 24.04 using the command:
sudo ubuntu-drivers install

because it was stuck on "Continue using a manually installed driver", and all other options were greyed out.
After updating I didn't choose any drivers thinking that the system would choose the driver and restart the system. After restarting, the internet option isn't available in the control panel and the settings menu. I have connected to the internet through Ethernet cable but still, the internet isn't working.


Now the system is using the "X.Org X server" driver which is shown in the Additional Drivers window:

I uninstalled the Nvidia drivers using the command sudo apt remove --purge nvidia* and restarted, but no use. Since there is no internet, I cannot download new drivers to fix this issue.

I couldn't find any fix but on a lot of searching, I found that I could boot into the previous kernel.
Restarted the system and from the grub menu -> Advanced Settings for Ubuntu, I chose the previous kernel (in my case it was 6.8.0-31-generic) and booted into my system
Now I could connect to the internet so I upgraded my system using apt.
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade


I did have network problems after kernel upgrade.
This answer helped me.

Find your current kernel version using uname -a:

Linux desktop 6.8.0-41-generic


Load into previous kernel (where nework works) using GRUB. (For me it was 6.8.0-31-generic)
Install missing linux-modules-extra for your new kernel:

sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-41-generic


Reboot into new kernel.

